# Very significant question about degree for a programmer

Tags: education

I'm stuck now in choosing going to University or just learn programming by myself (I have secondary professional education), I got it from Kyrgyzstan it's from CIS countries.
I would love to listen to proffesional programmers or other people who got the job abroad as a programmer (in Europian Countries or America) how often do companies require bachelor degree and is it more valuable than work experience? Should I go to University or I can just got two year of work experience here in C# and I will be ready for applying for a job abroad? Thanks anyone for answer!!

Comment: Could you specify more precisely where you want to work abroad? In some countries (e.g. in Europe) I believe you may need a university degree, sometimes as a legal requirement for a work permit.

Comment: For example Ireland, I've read that some companies only look at your experience and knowledge in proper area of expertise, so that's why I thought good experience would be equal to college education

Comment: It really depends on the company. More employers will be interest in you if you have a degree and good grades than if you don't, all else being equal. On the other hand, some employers are starting to think that enough kids have basic programming skills these days that it may be worth hiring them and training them specifically to the company's needs. On the other other hand, that latter may or may not be an issue next time you are job hunting, and may or may not limit your career growth.  The most important thing a degree with good grades demonstrates is that you have learned how to learn...

Comment: In practice, a 'degree' is not at all necessary to actually do the job.  Some companies, for whatever reason, just want the line item on the CV.  I look at the education to see if a candidate spent their time, and money, wisely.

Comment: For a work visa, it is entirely possible that it is a hard requirement, because some countries require proof (for "knowledge worker visas") that the company cannot find employees locally, and if someone without a degree can get hired from Kyrgyzstan, why not someone without a degree from the local country?

Answer (score 3):

Going to a University will always be a plus. The most important thing about it is not the degree itself, but the possibility to learn all of the relevant skills in a structured and well-thought-out manner. You will also have classmates to lean on when there's something you don't understand.

In the long run, work experience is far more important than a degree. However, if you don't have a degree, you might find it quite difficult to get into the industry in the first place.

Most (if not all) programming skills *can* be obtained online, but then you need to know exactly what to look for and essentially do the exact same thing you would do in a university, but without any help from others.

The choice is yours, but my recommendation is that you go to a university.

Comment: Thanks for answer! The thing is in our country Universities don't give you proper skills in programming, and I have two choives, finish learning programming and go to the job that doesn't require education degree, get some experience and then start searching jobs abroad. But now I'm not really sure will my secondary professional education that I obained from college suitable for applying for job.

Comment: Well, if the universities in your country can't teach you the skills you need in your professional life, then you have no reason to study there. But don't worry, a lot of programmers are self-taught. Employers tend to test your skills before they hire you. So as long as you teach yourself the relevant skills and are clear with potential employers that you have those skills, you should be fine.

Comment: Damn, thanks a lot, I'm more confident now

Answer (score 2):

A University degree looks a lot better on an application than 'Two years self-taught'.

A uni degree means little in terms of skill. But, it does mean you have been taught how to learn and can interact with groups of people. Which is important at entry level.

Comment: What about two years experience of programming at real work without degree against university degree?

Comment: No idea, it would mean nothing to me, but might work with others